# matplotlib open an existing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have tried to find solutions to this problem on this site, for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621017/matplotlib-re-open-a-closed-figure/9621119#9621119), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729948/matplotlib-how-to-show-a-figure-that-has-been-closed), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419626/how-to-close-a-show-window-but-keep-the-figure-alive/25422314#25422314).

I work in engineering, and spend a lot of time plotting data, re-plotting it, adjusting this and that to see how to extract the most information from it in a python shell. However, it's a real pain to each time re-create the plot I want as a new figure. What I want is to be able to re-open a closed figure. Actually, I want to be able to *open a figure at all in the pyplot interface*.

Typically my workflow might look something like this. I might create a new figure and axes with a call to subplots():

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Then, I create my plots, perhaps just a simple line plot:

```
ax.plot(someExistingData)
```

Now, I will show the plot, using the only way I know how:

```
plt.show()
```

Now, after inspecting the plot, I notice that the range is not what I would like, or I want to change the linewidth, or I want to display with circle markers instead of a continuous line, or any of a million things. What I would like to do at this point, after closing the original plot (hitting the red X on the figure that pops up on my computer), is something like:

```
plt.open(fig)
plt.show()
```

My understanding is that matplotlib's state interface is only able to find recently-created plots. From the matplotlib documentation about what `plt.show()` does:

"Display all open figures."

Great, but how do I open a figure in the first place without creating it from scratch? This seems like a simple task. I have an existing figure -> I want to add it to the list of figures matplotlib thinks is "open", and then I want to show that figure with `plt.show()`. However, I can't seem to find a way to "re-open" an *existing figure*, or even explicitly "open" a figure at all. I *know* the figure object still exists, and that figure object *still contains* my old axis that I want to display, I just want to add that figure object to whatever interface matplotlib uses for displaying it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib: how to set the current figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986567/matplotlib-how-to-set-the-current-figure)

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987462/1275942. Basically, if you call plt.figure() with a number or tag, you can select it again by calling plt.figure() with the same number.

Comment: @Keon When I attempt to call plt.figure(fig.number) the figure that 'attaches' to the pyplot interface has zero Axes, while the fig object still has 1. Showing that with plt.show() gives an empty axes.

Comment: What backend are you using? I've had some issues where the inline backend flushes plots after ploting them